# No Image display in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a simple windows form application C#, that is supposed to show a picture.  I am following a tutorial from [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/picturebox) Following is the code of form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Construct an image object from a file in the local directory.
        // ... This file must exist in the solution.
        Image image = Image.FromFile("Picture1.png");
        // Set the PictureBox image property to this image.
        // ... Then, adjust its height and width properties.
        pictureBox1.Image = image;
        pictureBox1.Height = image.Height;
        pictureBox1.Width = image.Width;
    }
}
```

The image is present in the solution folder, but still nothing is displayed in the window when the application is run. There is no compilation error.

**Update**

[image]

Its solved now.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the PictureBox click event handler is registrated. It is not sufficient to copy the example code. (I'm just guessing)

[image]

Comment: +1. Looks like the original code was in VB.NET and event wiring did not get converted.

Comment: I selected  pictureBox1_Click from the drop down adjacent to Click. But still no gain

Comment: As Simon Whitehead points out, the file path could be the problem. If it is an option for you, add the image to the project resources (right click on the project > Properties > Resources > Add Resource > Add Existing File. This will embed the image in the assembly. You can then access it with `Properties.Resources.picturename`. No file path required!

Comment: @gpuguy: your code is missing `pictureBox1 += New EventHandler(pictureBox1_Click);` after `InitializeComponent`. Or are you saying it's done behind the scenes? Did you check that `pictureBox1_Click` is being fired by putting a breakpoint there?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I added the file in resource. What changes I have to do now in code ?

Comment: Well `pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.picturename;`

Answer (score 1):

Without a full path, the image won't load from the solution directory.. it will load from the directory where your executable is executed from.. which is either the Debug or Release folders when you're running from Visual Studio.. depending on what Profile you're running it with.

So put the image in the /bin/Debug folder and run your program again.

Answer (score 0):

A better option would be to add this image to the project and do either of the two:

- Add as a resource. It can later be used with strong typing.
- Set this option on the file: `Copy to Output Directory = Copy if newer`.

It is not a good practice to add anything manually under `/bin/`, because those folders are volatile and can be erased by Visual Studio at any moment (usually on the next rebuild).